# iTextSharp PDF Writer - font issue

Tags: fonts, itext

I use iTextSharp to write my .Net information into a PDF file.

This works great when I use the following line:

```
bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

however, when I try to change to Arial using the following line:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font bf = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

I get an error on this line:

```
float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 8);
```

The error is: 
"NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code".

Maureen

Comment: Did you register a font program for Arial? I don't see you doing that anywhere in your code.

Comment: I didn't think I had to. This article (https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/81/itextsharp-working-with-fonts)  indicates "This method will work directly with all fonts registered by iTextSharp, which includes all fonts found in the Windows default font directory. On Win XP Pro, that's usually C:/WINDOWS/Fonts. " I ran the script in that article to list all registered fonts and I do see "Arial" on the list. Is there a specific overload I need to use to make the bf.GetWidtPoint(text,8) to work? Or do I still need to Register and embed arial??